# `ps | grep | kill` aborts my script prematurely

Tags: shell-script, process, kill, ps

I have a Linux computer that I remotely SSH into using [plink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/plink) on a `Windows XP` machine. I have a Plink program set to execute commands in a script using automated login:

```
plink -ssh [domain name] -l [username] -pw [password] -m commands.txt >> Outputtext.txt
```

`commands.txt` only contains the following

```
echo "Killing process"
ps -ef | grep 'processname' | awk ‘{print $2}’ | head -n 1` | xargs kill -9
sleep 2
echo "Restarting process"
processd &

echo "Exiting..."
```

This script simply searches for a processname kills it then restarts it. It works everytime if the process is actually started on linux before I execute the script. However, if the process is NOT started it will actually kill the controlling terminal and exit `plink.exe` right on the `ps -ef` command.

I've narrowed it down to when I'm doing the `ps -ef | grep 'processname'` it will return two PID's one is the process I'm searching for, and the other is the grep processname PID itself

When the process isn't started it will only return one PID the `grep 'processname'` and I think `kill -9` is killing that and somehow killing plink connection or the controlling terminal? Is there any way around this?

or to check if the `grep 'processname'` returns 2 lines meaning the process started, or if there is only 1 line then don't kill it.

Not sure if I can `echo "#!bash"` a bash script out and then have the bash script execute?

Or is this a weird bug in plink?

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend using `pkill` instead of the `ps|grep|...` pipeline you're using now. `pkill` is immune to the problem you noted, whereby `grep` on the process list finds the `grep` process itself. (There are tricks to avoid that, but `pkill` is cleaner, IMO.)

Comment: what about `pgrep -f /path/of/programm`

Comment: yes, also you can use `killall -9 programmname` or `pkill` as Steven suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your command line seems really weird to me:

```
ps -ef | grep 'processname' | awk ‘{print $2}’ | head -n 1 | xargs kill -9
```

1. You feed `awk` (i.e. a program which can perfectly filter its input, the much mightier program) with the output of `grep`.
2. You pipe the output of `awk` (i.e. a program which can perfectly filter its output) into `head`.
3. You use `xargs` for definitely just one argument.

So independently of better approaches (and this question being a duplicate) I feel obliged to correct this:

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | awk '/processname/ {print $2;exit;}')
```

Comment: Good catch, even though if we're strict, piping `ps -ef` to `grep` is in fact redundant considering that `ps` provides the `-C` option just for this purpose. (see also Ignacio's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Restrict `ps` to only find the command and output the info you care about.

```
ps -C processname -o pid
```

You may want to check the result code of the command before trying to actually kill anything though.

Comment: Oh thank you! I have another (related) question. I dont have disown or nohup installed on this linux machine, and the process I start through the plink script is bound to the plink (terminal). Is there anyway to start the process from the plink session so that the output could be available to any connecting terminal?

Because if the plink session ends, the output from the started process doesn't display on another terminal for some reason only the original terminal that started the process

Comment: Run the command in a detached `screen`.

Comment: not sure I understand?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen

Comment: ah sh: Command not found? wow this linux box doesn't have anything installed nohup, screen, disown, its an openlinux embedded system